# Making Window Topmost with Python and/or Windows API

Tags: python, winapi

I'm trying to write a piece of code which finds a target window (returns its handler), brings it to top, and makes it topmost. The problem is that I cannot make the window topmost.

```
HWND_TOPMOST = -1
SWP_NOSIZE = 1
SWP_NOMOVE = 2
hwnd = ctypes.windll.user32.FindWindowW(None, title) # works OK
ctypes.windll.user32.BringWindowToTop(hwnd) # works OK
ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE) # doesn't work
```

How to make the window topmost?

Note: I cannot install third-party libraries, modules, etc. Thus, I need to use Python native modules and/or Windows API.

Comment: You need to check [SetWindowPos document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos#remarks) which introduces the points of attention when using `HWND_TOPMOST`.

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT, thank you for your comment! I tried playing with that info but without luck. What's interesting, my `VBA` version of the code works without any issues. I'm actually trying to transfer the code from `VBA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a solution. It looks like `ctypes` cannot convert a negative `int` (`HWND_TOPMOST`) to `HWND` type. Thus, `HWND` function from `ctypes.windtypes` module should be used.

```
import ctypes.wintypes

ctypes.windll.user32.SetWindowPos(hwnd, ctypes.wintypes.HWND(HWND_TOPMOST), 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE)
```